# Line cut off (doesn't fit) in map -- any cartographic convention?

Tags: line, cartography

Anyone would know if there is any cartographic convention on representing/symbolizing a line that doesn't fit on my layout map? Should I represent it using an arrow at the end.. or something else?

Info: I am plotting an oil field with multiple pipelines, and some of those goes off my focus area, should I symbolize them in a different way to represent that they actually continue?

Comment: Not sure about piplines, but considering maps containing rivers, roads etc., almost always the line simply ends at the outer frame of the map. I guess the almost universal (silent) convention is that readers suppose a line is continuing if it reaches the boundary of the map canvas: that's how most maps work. If I google for `pipeline map`, I find maps that handle that issue exactly like this. I would compare maps from your domain of activity to see how others dealt with that issue.

Comment: Oh dear, the "cartography is all opinion-based, non-GIS stuff" sentiment from the dreaded question-closers is out again. Shame on you! This is a perfectly good question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a definitive cartographic convention but when preparing survey plans if there's a line that's important to the map (reference mark connections, road centrelines, etc.) then we'll end it with an arrow indicating that continues. There's always a text explanation assosciated with the arrow indicating what it's pointing at, e.g. "To RM{No.}/SSM{No.}" in the case of connections, "To {town}" in the case of a road.

If the pipe/well network is the point of your map then I would use an arrow and let the audience know where it goes.

Edit: bracket style

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes an arrow is used. Sometimes annotation, such as "From oilfield X" or "To refinery Y" is used. Or both.

Make sure to have the line terminate at an obvious *neatline* -- a cartographic line that clearly separates the area being mapped from the *marginalia* which is stuff on the map sheet that is not actual map.

If there's no neatline, make sure, if the pipeline (or road, etc) has a *casing* -- its own outline around its own color -- that the casing does not exist at the cut-off part of the line symbol.

Everything you do should let the map user know, consciously or subconsciously, that the linear feature does not terminate at the end of the symbol.